# Facebook Javascript SDK and CSP

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK in my web application that I protected with CSP.
I added "connect.facebook.net" in my "script-src" CSP list and the SDK is loading.

But it looks like the SDK is trying to evaluate a string as Javascript

[image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://upload.info.free.fr/bc/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-07%20at%2010.50.15%20PM.png))</sub>

How can I use the Facebook SDK without having to add "'unsafe-eval'" in my CSP? Is there a CSP-friendly version of this SDK?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use the Facebook SDK without 'unsafe-eval', because  the Facebook SDK requires it.

Comment: is this still true in 2020?

Comment: @user1709076 it's true in 2021 :)